# Latex algpseudocode IF with multiple conditions

Tags: latex

I'm trying to write a pseudo code with Latex in my paper where I need to put a IF condition which has multiple conditions. I'm trying this but doesnt seem to work as the \Or command is not recognized:

```
\begin{algorithmic}

\While{$condition$}
    \State $do-something$

    \If {$condition-1$ \Or $condition-2$ \Or $condition-3$}
        \State $break$
    \EndIf

\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
```

I'm using the algpseudocode package. Also I need to put a "space" within the conditions, but latex just discards it and connects the two words together, any way to do this?

Cheers,

Comment: (La)TeX-related questions are better suited on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com). Since you've "figured it out", you could type up your own solution as an answer, and then flag this for migration to TeX.SE. Alternatively, this would be considered "too localized".

Answer (score 11):

Nevermind guys, found out. This is the correct way

```
\begin{algorithmic}

\While{$condition$}
    \State $do-something$

    \If {$condition$ $1$ OR $condition$ $2$ OR $condition$ $3$}
        \State $break$
    \EndIf

\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
```

Comment: Try \If {$condition$ {\bf or} $condition$}